# Does Rangefinder do anything on bows besides increase the zoom?

Tags: destiny-2

Rangefinder is a perk that has the following effect:

- *Aiming this weapon increases its effective range and zoom magnification. Increased projectile velocity while aiming Rocket Launchers and Grenade Launchers.*

Does this perk do anything else on bows besides increase the zoom magnification? I'm unable to find any answers for this, since Bows do not have a range perk or any damage falloff seemingly, and the projectile velocity in the description states only RLs and GLs.